# PHP glob() doesnt find .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, glob

Simple question - How to list `.htaccess` files using `glob()`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`glob()`](http://php.net/glob) does list "hidden" files (files starting with `.` including the directories `.` and `..`), but only if you explicitly ask it for:

```
 glob(".*");
```

Filtering the returned `glob()` array for `.htaccess` entries with [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/preg_grep):

```
 $files = glob(".*") AND $files = preg_grep('/\.htaccess$/', $files);
```

The alternative to glob of course would be just using [`scandir()`](http://php.net/scandir) and a filter ([`fnmatch`](http://php.net/fnmatch) or regex):

```
 preg_grep('/^\.\w+/', scandir("."))
```

Comment: The actual peculiarity is that PHP doesn't just make the `glob.h` system call constant `GLOB_PERIOD` available. So it's more of a circumvention.

Comment: Yeah, added the code, it's quite long to make use of that parameter value format to get those files starting with period. I wonder why the constant has not been integrated. Is that windows loving?

Comment: I would just call this a bug. Lets take a practical use-case: delete all files, including dot files from a folder: `array_map('unlink', glob(__DIR__."/*/folder/*.*"));`. Expected result: all files gone- but this won't work. A simple wildcard won't work, too: `array_map('unlink', glob(__DIR__."/*/scripts/webinterface/*"));`. One would have to combine the glob patterns to match both: `{.*,*.*}` (dotfiles + all files). And i guess, if i file it as bug i would get expected behavior as response and a direct close... =).

Answer (score 0):

in case any body come to here,

since the `SPL` implemented in PHP, and offers some cool iterators, you may make use of the to list your hidden files such as `.htaccess` files or it's alternative hidden linux files.

using `DirectoryIterator` to list all of directory contents and excluding the `.` and `..` as follows:

```
$path = 'path/to/dir';
$files = new DirectoryIterator($path);

foreach ($files as $file) {
    // excluding the . and ..
    if ($file->isDot() === false) {
        // make some stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I am going to go this route for my current project, but ...I have concerns: http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php#122474  Have you experienced any similar obstacles?

Comment: Just ran some tests on my wamp and `->isDot()` was gobbling up my `.htaccess` files with `.` and `..`.  Perhaps if someone wishes to fully investigate and post a Note in the manual it would be helpful to future researchers.  http://php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.isdot.php  A literal check for `.` and `..` seems necessary.

Comment: " Have you experienced any similar obstacles?" Nope, Your code working normally, I had tested it on a Windows server with php5.6 and it works fine, excluding the `.` and `..` and the `.DB_STORE` file in your case, also it does not exclude the .htaccess file

Comment: Applying your code in a directory with the following contents `.htaccess , .DB_STORE , a.htaccess` gived the following output : https://i.imgur.com/fWWCTa9.png